# When do we use this construction? Auxiliary verb + subject + verb

Tags: verbs, nouns, auxiliary-verbs, construction

I was trying to find some info about this construction but couldn't succeed, although I happen to encounter it here and there almost every day. So the construction is: auxiliary verb + subject + verb. Noteworthy that it looks like a question construction, but it actually isn't.

Example: *Very rarely **does she manage** to handle her work.*

This sentence can be replaced with *She very rarely manages to handle her work.*

So in what cases should we use it? And when would it be inappropriate to do it?

Comment: Look up "inversion for emphasis". It has been done quite a lot here on EL&U.

Comment: @Cascabel It's not inversion for emphasis, really. It's a grammatical rule which applies when a negative adjunct is placed at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: @Araucaria Is there another name for it? That's what we used to call it when I was teaching EFL. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/477816/especially-verb-subject/478054#478054)  would seem to agree with me that is some kind of umbrella term, although it does say that "intro adverbial inversion" is the formal name. Also [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73435/inversion-past-tense/73438#73438) from Barrie England.

Comment: BTW...the question was "When do we use the ...construction ' auxiliary verb + subject + verb'." The example had a negative adjunct, but from the way the question is phrased I would not limit it to that.

Comment: Notice that _very rarely_ is negative. If you substituted _very often_ the sentence would be ungrammatical. This is just [Subject-Auxiliary Inversion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/101123/15299) with Negative preposing.

Comment: Fronting of the negative "rarely" triggers subject-auxiliary inversion. There would be some reason for fronting it, and that could be for emphasis.